# Resizing dijit.Layout.ContentPanes within dijit.Layout.ContentBorder

Tags: html, css, dijit.layout

I have two dijit layout ContentPanes within a dijit layout ContentBorder. I am have tried to set up styles so that everything resizes dynamically, but am still seeing issues. In all browsers, full screen makes the the map content pane covers the rightPane. The map class does not seem to be resizing dynamically, only the rightPane.

The panes are set up like this:

```
<body class="claro">

  <div id="content"
       data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
       data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true"
       style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">

      <div id="rightPane"
           data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
           data-dojo-props="region:'right'">

          <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
              <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane"
                   data-dojo-props="title:'Légende', selected:true">
                  <div id="legendDiv"></div>
              </div>
              <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
                   data-dojo-props="title:'Pane 2'">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="map"
           data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
           data-dojo-props="region:'center'"
           style="overflow: hidden;">
      </div>
      <div id="search"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

The css:

```
html, body {
  height: 97%;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 1%;
}

#search {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 20px;
   left: 74px;
}

#rightPane {
  width: 20%;
}

#map {
  width: 80%;
}

#legendPane {
  border: solid #97DCF2 1px;
}
```

**UPATE**
Playing around with the css values, I set the map class to 75% width and left the right pane class at 20%. This gives a decent result, until the window is resized:

This looks closer to what I have in mind (not nitpicking about the uneven top edge yet...but I'm open to suggestions):

[image]

But when I resize and enlarge the window, this happens:

[image]

When the map width value is set to 78%, the content panes overlap:

[image]

Never used jsfiddle before, but I tried to put the app on [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jyrdh8jy/1/) with some sample services. Let me know if you can access this or not...